# Is JRE used in IBM products different to the ones we download from Oracle site?

Tags: java, wtx

Is the JRE used by the IBM products like WTX different from the usual ones? When I tried to use a class compiled using usual JVM it doesn't seem to work in WTX.

If so I don't see the JDK in the IBM installed directory to compile my java source. Can someone help me how to get the JDK for the IBM products.

Answer (score 0):

WTX uses it's own JRE.
You can find it on the install dir of the designer.

For example:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere Transformation Extender X.X\java
```

Regards,
B.